Выдернуть функцию из бандла Webpack
Есть чужой сайт, написанный на React и упакованный Webpack-ом.
Это сайт букмекерской конторы. И мне нужно научиться очищать купон вызовом соответствующей функции.
Я открываю консоль и вижу в нем контейнер JS модулей в виде двумерного массива такого вида:

Меня например интересует модуль 932.
Я иду по ссылке [FunctionLocation], вижу JS код этого модуля:

и где то ниже в этом модуле я вижу интересующую меня функцию removeAll у купона:

Мне нужно ее как то вызвать. Она просто посылает соответствующий ПОСТ запрос на АПИ сайта.
Она без параметров.
Если я в консоли пишу webpackChunkdesktop["3"][1]["932"] - то вижу просто JS код этого
модуля.  Я точно знаю, что это можно как то сделать.
Хотя бы подскажите направление куда копать)

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Александр, я сознательно использовал изображения для иллюстрации проблемы, т.к. здесь  не столь важен сам код, как важен контекст и зрительное восприятие проблемы.  Также красиво показать вывод консоли с помощью тегов кода я не смогу, это будет не информативно и потеряется контекст проблемы.

webpackChunkdesktop["3"][1]["932"] - это сама фукнция. Надо смотреть внутри, где и как возвращается объект из let S в котором лежит нужный вам метод. Для начала попробуйте что то вроде этого console.log(webpackChunkdesktop["3"][1]["932"]()) но туда надо передать 3 параметра каких то. Ну или выяснить, что такое r.E и s.dH.post, написать собственную функцию создать ее в консоли и вызвать

Получается, что мой вопрос можно перефразировать так: как получить все экспортируемый функции всех модулей вебпака?

Ну всех не всех, но нужную цепочку - точно
